# Determine whether a document is being edited

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to run a background agent (lotusscript preferably) to edit several documents in my database. In beforehand I want to check all the documents and if 1 of them is currently being edited by another user, I want to cancel my agent.

Is there a way to determine whether a document is currently being edited without setting a field and saving in QueryOpen / PostOpen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkmark database's property "Allow document locking". This enables document locking for database.

You can check then if a document is beeing edited by a user with

```
If doc.LockHolders(0) <> "" then
    ' doc is in use by a user
End If
```